# angular2.4 and web component don't execute template rendering in callbacks in edge and firefox

Tags: angular, web-component, polyfills

I have an application ng2 that runs in another web page
The internal rung with web components

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/webcomponent/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <base href="/appfiglia/">
    <app-root></app-root>
    <link rel="import" href="/appfiglia?param=<%=Server.URLEncode(Request("param")) %>">
```

I'm using Shadow DOM
In chrome and browse that uses webkit all works well.
Ma on firefox or edge and in fuction buond to the templates or in the callback of the promises,it happens that the new data are no  mkore bound to the template. 
**The refresh oh the page happens no more!**

I caould solve by instantiating cd: ChangeDetectorRef and then inside tha callbacks write:

this.cd.markForCheck();
this.cd.detectChanges();

Updating template by function like *ngIf="isActive()" seems impossible.

In the main thread code all go regularly. In chrome all works without forcing rendering.
How can i solve without rewrite all callbacks?

*Enviroment:*

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.5
node: 7.5.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.7
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
```